# How can low-rep user request migration?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question 6 weeks ago that has remained unanswered here on Server Fault.  A commenter suggested that it would have been better asked on unix.stackexchange.com, but I cannot migrate the question myself and I'm reluctant to simply re-ask the same question over there for fear that it violates some site rules.  What can I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Flag it for moderator attention. Community mods can do arbitrary question migrations to any site.

-- or --

Delete the question, and re-ask it on the other site. I think this is fine in cases where the question didn't get any answers, but you *really* should delete it first before asking again. I would also strongly recommend polishing up the question a bit and improving it, so it has a better chance on the 2nd try.